# Effectively saving using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I am using MagicalRecord in my iOS app, and not sure about the right way to save.

My app is about chatting, and every time the logged in user received a message, I need to update a time token.

Now I do like this:

> [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
>
> ```
>     User *currentUser = [User MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" 
>                                             withValue:@(_CURRENT_USER_ID) 
>                                             inContext:localContext];
>
>     currentUser.lastChatMessageTimeToken = [NSDate date]; 
> }];
> ```

However, I believe it is not efficient because once the user logged in, his id is determined, and the currentUser is always the same.

I am thinking I should cache the currentUser as a instance variable, but cannot find corresponding MagicalRecord method to perform.

Also, I was told not to cache a NSManagedObject because it is bind to a context.

So I am not sure what I should do. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that fetching, then updating, and finally saving a single object is not very efficient. You can hold on to a reference of your currentUser object as long as you know which context to which it belongs. From there, your code will look something like this;

```
currentUser = //from somewhere else, a property perhaps
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    User *localUser = [currentUser MR_inContext:localContext];
    localUser.lastChatMessageTime = [NSDate date];
}];
```

Fetching the object by object ID is going to be faster than performing a fetch request. However, since you're only changing one object, I would recommend just saving on the current thread (as long as the context is also on the correct thread):

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = //....
User *currentUser = //from somewhere, and create in the context

currentUser.lastChatMessageTime = [NSDate date];

[context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

This way there are no blocks to deal with, and you don't have to perform the save on a background queue since this single record update will likely be fast enough even on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me the difference between  saveToPersistentStoreAndWait and saveOnlySelfAndWait? I tried to call them on [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext], but the latter seems not saving at all.

Comment: saveOnlySelfAndWait does what the name says. This is regard to nested contexts with parents. If you only save one level, then you need to call save on the parent again to persist the changes to disk (assuming the parent context is connected to the coordinator)

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768124/magicalrecord-how-to-save-imported-data-in-background My issue is regarding `MR_inContext:` returning nil for a just created user object.