# MagicalRecord: How to save imported data in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm trying to import data into Core Data and save it in a background thread with *MagicalRecord*.

I'm basically trying to do this:

```
__block User *user = nil;
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)
{
     user = [User MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:userId inContext:localContext];
     [user MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:responseObject];
}];

[User setCurrentUser:user];
```

User is correct when I'm inside the block. After the block is completed `user` is a *NSManagedObject* object, but doesn't have any attributes set.

This, on the other hand, works:

```
OEUser *user = [OEUser MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:userId];                               
[user MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:responseObject];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
[User setCurrentUser:user];
```

But I want to save it in the background.

---

I also tried this to no avail.

```
User *user = [User MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:userId];
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)
{
     User *localUser = [user MR_inContext:localContext];
     [user MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:responseObject];
}];

[User setCurrentUser:user];
```

The problem here seems to be that `[user MR_inContext:localContext]` returns *nil*.

I'm pretty new to Core Data, so bear with me if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `*Wait` method you are not gaining any asynchronicity and you will still be blocking your main thread during the import. You should indeed be using the block methods but this to ensure that any Core Data operations are performed on the correct thread (the thread the `NSManagedObjectContext` was created on).

When you use `saveWithBlockAndWait:` MagicalRecord creates a new context on a background thread to perform it's work on. This newly created context is then yielded to your block and lives only for the scope of the block. You can not pass `NSManagedObject`'s between contexts so you should not be trying to capture the user from outside the block.

I can imagine the second example will only actually be failing in the case of creating a new `User` because you call `MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:withValue:` which will create a new `NSManagedObject` in memory but this is not persisted to the store therefore inside the `saveWithBlockAndWait:` there is no `User` to pull from the store.

The correct way would be

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
  User *localUser = [User MR_findFirstOrCreateByAttribute:@"userId" 
                                                withValue:userId     
                                                inContext:localContext];
  [user MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:responseObject];
}];

User *user = [User MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"userId" withValue:userId];

[User setCurrentUser:user];
```

As mentioned this will block the main thread so you may want to consider moving to `saveWithBlock:completion:` instead which will perform the work in the background and not block the current thread.

Even better I would consider not holding onto an actual `User` object but instead hold onto the `userId`, which will safe you headaches down the line when people start accessing the `currentUser` from all kinds of threads

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Additional question: in my second failing example, is there any way of accessing the user created on the default context (that has not been persisted yet) from the block-created local context? Or the only way is persisting the default context beforehand?